# Implicit cast of string boolean to integer fails

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora, mysql-5.6, aws-aurora-serverless

We have a table with the following column

```
`IsDeleted` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
```

These work as expected in both our non-prod and prod environments

```
select * from mytable where IsDeleted = 0;
select * from mytable where IsDeleted = 1;
```

These statements work in non-prod, but not prod.

```
select * from mytable where IsDeleted = '0';
select * from mytable where IsDeleted = '1';
```

In production, both statements return no rows.  (though there are lots of rows in the DB)

All environments are Aurora Serverless v1 (MySql 5.6)
There's no differences in Global Variables/DB Options between the environments.

Not sure if the this something specific to Aurora,Serverless or MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that production had an index defined for the table with `IsDeleted` as the leading key that was not there in our non-prod environments.

Deleting that index allowed the queries that used implicit casting to start working.

I'd be curious if this is working as designed or some known bug.